# Is it possible to make a program that will find input messages that give each of the possible 512-bit strings from SHA-512?

Tags: hash, sha, sha512, sha2

Since there are more possible inputs than possible outputs (due to the pigeonhole principle), is there a way to create a program to create messages to get every possible output value?

Comment: Theoretically speaking, that's a semi-decidable problem, so the answer is "yes, if such a message exists for each SHA-512". Just brute force all possible strings, gradually increasing length, and you will get it. Checking whether there is an inverse image of every hash is another beast.

Comment: No problem.  If you can do one per nanosecond, it'll only take you about 2^512 nanoseconds.  You just have the slightly awkward issue that the universe will have undergone heat death in the meantime.

Comment: So, given an infinite timeframe, it is technically possible?

Comment: Yes, you could write a very short program to do so. The largest SHA-512 message has a bit length of (2\*\*64) - 1. So try every message of bit length 0, every message of bit length 1, ..., every message of bit length (2\*\*64) - 1 and you're done.